# Executing commands with PHP: using normal user, but its home directory is /root

Tags: apache-httpd, environment-variables, php

I'm using a custom compiled installation of Apache + PHP, listening on port `80`.

Apache is configured to run as a normal user, with the proper settings `User` and `Group` of the `httpd.conf` file.

After running apache as a service, with `apachectl`, there's one process `httpd` running by root, and 4 others running by that normal user.

The problem is this:

- When I run an external command by PHP (using `exec` or `passthru` for instance), it's run by the proper normal user, but `$HOME` environment variable points to `/root`.

For example, with the following very simple code:

```
<?php
echo "Home: " . `echo \$HOME`;
echo "<br />";
echo "Id: " . `id`;
```

I get:

```
Home: /root
Id: uid=1000(normaluser) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),17(audio),33(video)
```

Any command run this way, is actually run by the normal user, so there's no security problem. The major problem is when an external command is run, and that command tries to write and/or read something from the home directory.

Comment: I asked this question on superuser site, but it didn't receive enough attention, so I deleted it and re-asked it here.

Comment: What's normaluser's entry in /etc/passwd?

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the `echo $HOME` just reads the environment variable set by whatever shell starts `httpd` (the Apache process).  Unless something does `export HOME=/home/whatever`, the value of environment variable HOME will stay the same.

I'm not sure that your last paragraph is correct at all. As far as no security problem, does `PATH` get set to that of `normaluser`? What if /home/normaluser/bin contains a very special `ls` executable, that does unusual things, like produce downloadable HTTP output of any file on the system?  On my Apache/PHP setup, PATH gets set to `/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/u/bediger/bin` for the PHP program.

Your assertion about the major problem, reading/writing something from the home directory, doesn't make sense either. The value of HOME isn't important for partially-qualified file names, the current working directory matters. `httpd` seems to set that correctly for my test PHP program. My Apache/PHP setup sets current working directory to the document root, which is where my PHP lives.

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<p>
<?php
    echo "Home: " . `echo \$HOME`;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Id: " . `id`;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "PWD: " . `pwd`;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "PATH: " . `echo \$PATH`;
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```